# Internet Explorer 9's magically expanding div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

Well I'm stumped with this one. As you can see if you view [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RLpSa/) with Internet Explorer 9, there's a div that expands automatically on hover. No javascript required! Anyway, I checked the css with the [W3C validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http://fiddle.jshell.net/RLpSa/show/&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en) and it shows several errors, but as far as I can tell they are due to vendor specific properties, or at least I haven't been able to find syntax errors, etc. I suspect this particular class could be too much for IE 9:

```
div.gridViewScrollerH
{
    width: 916px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -ms-overflow-x: auto;
    -ms-overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Has anyone had this problem before? Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: IE9 doesn't need `-ms-overflow-x` or `-ms-overflow-y`. Those are aliases of `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` respectively, so there is no reason to use them if you already use the unprefixed versions (they have no effect if you do).

Comment: This is more of an auto vs hidden overflow issue I think. Some combinations of values won't work for example.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, I didn't have those orginally. I added those lines when I started to get desperate :p

Answer (score 19, accepted):

just add `display: inline-block;` to the class

```
div.gridViewScrollerH
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 916px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -ms-overflow-x: auto;
    -ms-overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. `display: inline-block` I meant. I fixed answer. Thnx BoltClock

Comment: `display:inline-block` worked for me, too. In my case, only the notion `overflow:auto`caused this IE9 "magically expanding div" bug

Comment: An Update, it is working only with a fix width, if you have no width defined it won't work

Answer (score 2):

This problem specific to IE9. 
Make overflow style of the div to **scroll** , instead of applying auto.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding min-height: 0% in the class