# IE9 Bug ? Mysteriously growing DIV

Tags: css, html

I have the following little sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    table.Sample { width: 600px; table-layout: fixed; }
    table.Sample col { width: 60px; }
    table.Sample td { height: 20px; line-height: 20px; padding: 0px; }
    table.Sample input { width: 55px; height: 17px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border-width: 1px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="scrollDiv" style="width: 400px; overflow: auto; background-color: #CCCCCC;">
        <table class="Sample">
            <colgroup><col /><col /><col /><col /><col /><col /><col /><col /><col /><col /></colgroup>
            <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="text" /></td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
            <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</HTML>
```

This works ok on IE8, IE10, Chrome, FireFox, Safari, ... but it bugs on IE9.

When I start typing into the text box, the div grows in height. The scrollbar does not move, but the div grows below the scrollbar.

I can't define the height of the div in css as the number of lines is variable and I'm not sure the scrollbar will be present (as the number of columns is variable in the real example).

I can solve the problem with the following javascript code, but I was wondering I was doing something wrong to provoke the error.

```
var div = document.getElementById('scrollDiv');
div.style.height = div.offsetHeight  + "px";
```

Thanks

Comment: Does giving the `td` an `overflow:hidden` help ?

Comment: No, that doesn't help.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a bug in IE9 with how it handles overflow-x:auto. Adding display:inline-block to the css for the div worked great for me. Source:

[Internet Explorer 9's magically expanding div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353256/internet-explorer-9s-magically-expanding-div)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with overflow, you can fix it using these CSS rules on your scrollDiv

```
overflow: auto;
overflow-x:scroll;
```

see here: http://cssdesk.com/BAYcp

Comment: Indeed, that helps, but in that case the scrollbar would always be visible even when the table is small enough (in width) for the surrounding div. (In the real example the number of columns is variable)

Comment: You only wanted to stop the height growing ;-) what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's a table with a variable number of columns and lines, but I only want an horizontal scrollbar when needed, not a vertical. You css fix helps against the IE9 bug, but I would prefer the horizontal scrollbar only to appear when needed.

Comment: You can always use conditional comments to target IE9 only for the CSS fix, leaving it as it for other browsers

Comment: I guess the question is not really how to fix it (as it is fixed using javascript) but more what is the cause of it ? I guess it's an IE9 bug as all other browser (even earlier version of IE) presents no such problem. But how to avoid making IE9 bug that way (in css) with the same visual output?

Comment: Multipl IE versions are known for their buggy treatment of the overflow property, there's a whole host of overflow related bugs :)