# CSS Error, MouseOver Link Moves Text in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drupal, drupal-7

I have an issue involving CSS and IE. In IE (IE 9), if I mouseover/hover over certain links then it moves text down. This does not happen when viewed with Firefox.

The example is at this link: http://www.debtdispatch.com/list_item_error.html

If you mouseover "Edit" or "Cancel" then it permanently moves the text underneath the table down.

I've tried:

- validating the page using the W3C validator and correcting all errors
  found
- adding styles to the table
- adding styles to links
- forcing IE 7 compatibility view

**Do you have any suggestions on how to fix it?**

*Edit: I would paste in the source code, but that appears to mess up the way that Stack Overflow displays.*

Comment: Something with DOCTYPE.. have you tried it with different one?

Comment: I tried changing it to simply <!DOCTYPE html>, but that didn't fix it.

I think that the issue lies in the CSS in this style sheet:
http://www.debtdispatch.com/sites/default/files/css/css_DA76D3kkHaT_VUm3Aj1Txz0yCM9z9qrYjWlPOR-gAwk.css

The stylesheets are automatically generated by a content management system (Drupal). I think that I need to override something in that style sheet, but I'm not sure exactly which one it is.

Comment: I tested with IE 9 mode and it worked fine. No issue.

Comment: Can't reproduce your bug

Comment: it looks gud in IE8, sorry no IE9.. possible suggestion a) remove `text-decoration: underline` from `a:hover` b) try fixing font-size and line-height in px for the elements to test c) test with table outside of div, ie without height constraint

Answer (score 2):

It looks like putting `display:inline-block;` on the div that contains the table should solve your problem. I tested the page using [Sauce](https://saucelabs.com/) and was able to recreate the issue. I found the solution on another [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13353425).

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that appears to fix it.